# Repeat Number Sequence in C

Tags: c

Can you help me fix my code?

Sample Input :

> 8 4

Sample Output :

> 1 2 3 4 1 2 3 4

Explanation:

8 is the limit of sequence numbers

4 is the maximum number that starts from 1

I can only write

```
for (i = 1; i <= limit_number; i++)
```

to make an output : 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8

What else do I need?

Comment: Hint: What's `i % 4` at each step?

Comment: You're not asking for help to FIX your code, You're asking for someone to DO your work for you. If you cannot do this exercise it means you need to take programming courses (which is fine, there's nothing wrong in that, everyone was a beginner one day).

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
int maximum = 4, limit_number = 8;
for(i = 0; i<limit_number; i++)
  printf("%d ", (i%maximum) + 1);
```